# Log Sobolev inequality for Wiener space

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am reading https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.1649.pdf and saw equation 10.2.3 that said that on Wiener space

$$E\left[f^2\log\left[\frac{f^2}{E[f^2]}\right]\right]\leq 2 E[|\nabla f|_H^2],$$

where $\nabla$ is the Malliavin derivative. I am curious, if we let $f^2$ be the Doleans-Dade stochastic exponential of a process $\Phi(t)$ satisfying Novikov's condition, then what does the right side give us? I know we have to compute a Malliavin derivative of the exponential. To this aim, I tried

$$\nabla \left(\exp\left(\int_0^T \phi(t) dB(t)-\frac12\int_0^T \phi^2(t) dt\right)\right)^{1/2}=\frac12\left(\exp\left(\int_0^T \phi(t) dB(t)-\frac12\int_0^T \phi^2(t) dt\right)\right)^{1/2}\nabla\left(\int_0^T \phi(t) dB(t)-\frac12\int_0^T \phi^2(t) dt\right).$$

Here I'm a bit stuck - if $\phi$ is deterministic, this is not hard to compute but what about in general?

I ultimately would like to see the right hand side of the LSI as the Fisher information.